# Find volume of region lying above $z=0$, below $z=4-x^2-y^2$ and inside extruded disc $x^2+y^2=2^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, plane-geometry

I am working on the following homework problem:

> Find the volume of the region that lies above the plane $z=0$, below the surface $z=4-x^2-y^2$ and inside the extruded disc $x^2+y^2=2^2$.

I think that, to find the volume, I need to precisely determine the $3$-$d$ region over which I need to integrate.
However, I am struggling to visualise the region.

What might be an effective way of visualising this region properly?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not the extruded disc a cylinder and that $z =4 - x^2-y^2 $ an inverted elliptic paraboloid

Volume $$= \int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{0}^{4-x^2-y^2} dzdydx$$ $$= 8\pi$$

Comment: these limits look correct to me.  However, how do I determine the function to integrate - that is, the integrand?

Comment: Volume is just defined as $\int\int\int_{D} dV = \int\int\int_{D}dzdydx$  There is no function to integrate

Comment: There are a lot of 3D grapher that you can put this function and visualize.

Comment: how can you tell that 'extruded disc' refers to a cylinder and how do you know the extent to which the cylinder extends?

Comment: $x^2+y^2 = 2^2$ is an equation that describes a cylinder and similarly $z=4-x^2-y^2$ is an elliptic paraboloid.  These are standard conics that you will get used to as you go through the course on conic sections

Comment: that explanation is helpful.  However, I thought that $x^2 + y^2 = 2^2$ is an equation that describes a circle, not a cylinder (which is a $3$-$d$ object).

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/QuadricSurfaces.aspx  Look at the explanation here.

Comment: @CKKOY In the  3-space equation of three variables if one variable is missing the surface is a cylinder extruded in the direction of missing variable. That is how you can recognize cylinder/extruded stuff.